# WCF Service 404 error

Tags: wcf, http, service, handler

I am trying to set up a WCF Service but I'm having a few problems. The service works and loads the wsdl page when I type in

```
www.mydomain.com/Service1.svc
```

However when I use

```
www.mydomain.com/Service1.svc/
```

or try to use any of the get methods I get

```
The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404.
```

My web.config file is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="PageHandlerFactory-ISAPI-4.0"/>
      <add name="PageHandlerFactory-ISAPI-4.0" path="*" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <remove name="ASP.NET-ISAPI-4.0-Wildcard"/>
      <add name="ASP.NET-ISAPI-4.0-Wildcard"
         path="*" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG"
         modules="IsapiModule"
         scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll"
         preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <remove name="svc-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="svc-Integrated-4.0" path="*" verb="*" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpHandlerFactory, System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
    </compilation>
    <httpHandlers>
      <remove verb="*" path="*.svc"/>
      <add path="*.svc" verb="*" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpHandler, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="RestService.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour" >
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="RestService.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="web">

        </endpoint>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://mydomain.com/Service1"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>

    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour" >
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>



    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

The Service.svc file is as follows :

```
namespace RestService
{
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public bool LoginUser( string Username, string password )
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

and the IService.cs is as follows:

```
namespace RestService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            //BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            UriTemplate = "login/{username}/{password}")]
        bool LoginUser(string username, string password);
    }
 }
```

The pipeline mode on the server is "Integrated" if that helps. I'm not sure what IIS version my hosting provider (pipeten) uses but I think it's 7.5 I have a feeling this has something to do with the URL validation however there is no option on my hosting to change this.

Comment: Show some of your service methods and the request url you are creating.

Comment: Are you hosting on IIS? Also do specify your IIS version and your environment

Comment: I have added more information to show the methods I have created!

Comment: This is not answering your question, but is there any reason why you are using this custom authentication instead of the standard basic authentication?

Comment: It was a just a temporary test that I was trying it on, I will probably changed to the standard later!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay turns out it was a simple mistake that I had made, I had missed out the . when adding the handler. Instead of path = "*" it should have been path=".*"

```
<add name="ASP.NET-ISAPI-4.0-Wildcard"
         path=".*" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG"
         modules="IsapiModule"
         scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll"
         preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
```